# Second monitor not working on Ubuntu 20.04 - Radeon

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, 20.04, radeon

I have two 17" LG Flatrons (L1730S and L1755S) connected to my not-so-new AMD desktop. One is plugged in via DVI, the other via HDMI using a DVI-to-HDMI adapter. It is not the adapter, because I've switched them around and the result is the same. Also, they were working fine as a dual display on 18.04.

Since upgrading to 20.04 I've been getting issues. Sometimes my second monitor (the 55) shows on settings as 'unknown display', sometimes as 'AlgolTek, Inc 13"', sometimes as 'LG Electronics 17"' as it should. But even when properly recognized, most times nothing shows up in it. Sometimes, I think randomly, it starts to work perfectly until I shut my PC down and then is back to black screen.

Also, sometimes when I try to change between mirror/extended/single display in settings, I get this weird thing in my working monitor (the 30), as you can see in the image. I revert settings and everything is back as it was.
[image: weird behaviour]
I've seen some similar threads but none exactly like my problem and, no being and advanced user, I'm afraid of tweaking things I don't understand and then regretting it later.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
```

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Richland [Radeon HD 8670D]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:39 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fef00000-fef3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i radeon
```

```
[    0.235651] smpboot: CPU0: AMD A10-6800K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics (family: 0x15, model: 0x13, stepping: 0x1)
[   14.714281] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   14.714319] radeon 0000:00:01.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 0: 0xc0000000 -> 0xcfffffff
[   14.714320] radeon 0000:00:01.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 2: 0xfef00000 -> 0xfef3ffff
[   14.714323] fb0: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
[   14.714477] radeon 0000:00:01.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   14.714849] radeon 0000:00:01.0: VRAM: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF (512M used)
[   14.714850] radeon 0000:00:01.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000020000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
[   14.714944] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[   14.714945] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[   16.926908] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[   17.609583] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[   17.609586] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0x0000000035309226
[   17.609973] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0x00000000b9c24ed9
[   17.629995] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c18 and cpu addr 0x00000000a8e437ec
[   17.629997] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c1c and cpu addr 0x00000000cc3dcf4c
[   17.629998] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c04 and cpu addr 0x00000000e3da78ce
[   17.629999] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c08 and cpu addr 0x00000000197addb9
[   17.630000] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0x00000000dd221798
[   17.630002] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c10 and cpu addr 0x000000007d5ab43f
[   17.630029] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   17.630065] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: using MSI.
[   17.630085] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   19.418579] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   19.756165] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   19.756250] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   19.773951] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem with Ubuntu 20.04, running a slightly older HP AMD-GPU laptop and connected to a single 4K external monitor via HDMI. In my case, I would get a green screen on the external monitor, and be unable to drop to shell to try and fix it. I still get a little bit of image tearing. My logs tell me nothing useful, so, it was mostly trial and error on my part.

You can try the following to get rid of tearing and problems with the external monitors.

- When you login, make sure it is Gnome with Wayland, anything else wouldn't work for me.
- Upgrade the kernel to the most recent stable version( [example](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html) ), at the time of writing this was 5.8.1, though it worked with 5.7 too. I had to compile the kernel as simply installing .deb kernel files didn't work. I don't understand the difference between the two.
- If the external monitor goes into power save mode, I often cannot recover the session and have to do a hard reboot.
- When logging in, I need to place the mouse cursor in the external monitor before I enter my password, otherwise I get the dreaded green screen.

It is likely we need to post a bug against Wayland, though I'm unsure whether this is the problem. Hope there is something useful in here for you.